# How to mock middleware authentication for unit test? Mocha, Chai and Sinon

Tags: typescript, express, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I have the following route:

```
router.post('/price-request/create', auth.middleware('jwt'), (req, res) =>
    priceRequestController.create(req, res)
  );
```

I need to test the controller, the controller has the following:

```
async create(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
    const { sub: azUserObjectId } = req.authInfo as { sub: string };

    const userTypeValue = await this.UserService.getUserType(azUserObjectId);

    if (userTypeValue.isFailure) {
      const codeError =
        (userTypeValue && userTypeValue.getError()?.code) ||
        httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
      res
        .status(codeError)
        .json({ errors: userTypeValue && userTypeValue.getError()?.message });
      return;
    }

    const updatedBody = {
      ...req.body,
      isToUpdate: false,
      user_type: userTypeValue.getValue(),
      created_by: azUserObjectId,
      status: PriceRequestStatusEnum.DRAFT
    };

    const priceRequestDto = this.priceRequestMapper.rawToReqDto(updatedBody);

    const errors = await validateDto(priceRequestDto);

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      res.status(httpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({ errors });
      logger.warn(' Errors found in the request', errors);
      return;
    }

    if (Array.isArray(priceRequestDto.email)) {
      priceRequestDto.email = priceRequestDto.email.join(';');
    }

    const priceRequest = await this.PriceRequestService.createPriceRequest(
      priceRequestDto
    );

    if (priceRequest && priceRequest.isSuccess) {
      res.status(httpStatus.OK).send(priceRequest.getValue());
      return;
    }
    const codeError =
      (priceRequest && priceRequest.getError()?.code) ||
      httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    res
      .status(codeError)
      .json({ errors: priceRequest && priceRequest.getError()?.message });
  }
```

But as you can see I have the route protected with a Middleware with passport, this is what it brings:

## **index.ts**

```
import passport from 'passport';
import { authMiddleware, bearerStrategy } from './auth.middleware';

passport.use(bearerStrategy);

export default {
  passportInstance: passport.initialize(),
  middleware: authMiddleware
};
```

## **auth.middleware.ts**

```
export const authMiddleware =
  (authType: authType) => (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    passport.authenticate(
      authType,
      { session: false },
      (
        err: { message: any },
        user: any,
        info: Express.AuthInfo | undefined
      ) => {
        if (err) {
          return res
            .status(httpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
            .json({ error: err.message });
        }

        if (!user) {
          return res
            .status(httpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
            .json({ error: 'Unauthorized' });
        }
        if (info) {
          req.authInfo = info;
          return next();
        }
      }
    )(req, res, next);
  };
```

Is there a way to stub and test my controller directly and omit the authentication middleware? and I need to send in the req the following attribute const { sub: azUserObjectId } = req.authInfo as { sub: string }; and I can think of doing it with chai-http, or is there a better way? Everythink is for the test with Mocha Chai and Sinon

Thank you very much

I am trying to find the best way to test my controller.